# Get array value with specific key format in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Consider following array and function:

```
$array = [
  'key' => [
    'key_2' => [
       'key_3' => 'Value 3'
    ]
  ],
];

function get_value( $key ) {
  echo $array . $key;
}
```

now I want to call the function like this:

```
get_value( 'key[key_2][key_3]' );
```

It gives error which is natural.

Possible to write `get_value` function in a way that it understands `'key[key_2][key_3]'` and gives the value?

Comment: Whilst it is possible, it might be a better idea if you explain why you're trying to do this, as there's more than likely a better, more standard, solution.

Comment: For starters, the `.` operator concatenates strings. You need to use `$array[$key]` to access the first level key. To access the second level key you would need `$array[$keyName1][$keyName2]`. Your string is `'key[key_2][key_3]'` is also non-sensical because key_2 doesn't contain an array with a key_3 inside. What is it exactly you want the function to do?

Comment: I understand why it's not working but I need to pass the key exactly like this to function *key[key_2][key_3]*. I thiought maybe it's possible to alter the *key[key_2][key_3]* in a way that we can get the value.

Comment: To start with, your array don't have `key[key_2][key_3]` since that would suggest that the `key` is an array containing `key_2` that would also be an array containing `key_3`.

Comment: Why is regex taged? Isn't arrays a better tag?

Comment: about regex tag, I thought it's possible via regex.

Comment: @fubar I just need to get the value in the nested array but I need to keep this format `key[key_2][key_3]` when calling the function.

Comment: @user3631047, yes, you've already explained that. My question is _why_? This is a very non-standard requirement, and you're most likely trying to do this, because of some poor design/coding decision made elsewhere, and as such this approach can be avoided.

Comment: I'm still unclear about what you expect that to return? Both `key_2` and `key_3`? Since both those keys are strings, I'm confused. Also, why use a function at all for that in the first place? Just do: `$value = $array['key_2'];`.

Comment: @fubar exactly, some other codes are forcing me to do this and there is no way around it to change the other codes. I need to keep this non-standard method.

Comment: _"some other codes are forcing me to do this"_ - How? If you have access to the array (which you need to be able to write it in the first place), why can't you just fetch the keys you need straight away?

Comment: Is the array always two levels deep or can it be a much deeper array?

Comment: I'm gonna vote to close this question as unclear since I've still haven't gotten any answer about the nested keys confusion. We still don't even know what the function is expected to return.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am not sure how to explain this, this is a requirement to get the key like explained. It's non-standard but it's a requirement.

Comment: @andreas It can be deeper.

Comment: As I pointed out, `key_2` and `key_3` are two different keys that both contains strings, so what would `key[key_2][key_3]` expect to return?

Comment: So what would it look like if it's deeper then? `'keykey2[key_2][key_3]'` or `'key_key2[key_2][key_3]'` how would the nested keys look? Too much details is missing.

Comment: @Andreas - This is starting to feel like a bottomless rabbit hole. I'm gonna split before I get sucked in deeper :-p

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I edited the array.  @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the input string seems to be used quite loosely I'm going to assume this can be manipulated to something easier to use.

Here I explode the keys and loop them and dig in the array til I'm out of keys.
Mind that the return can be either array or string/int/float/bool

```
function get_value($array, $key ) {
    $keys = explode(",", $key);
    Foreach($keys as $k){
        $array = $array[$k];
    }
    Return $array;
}

Var_dump(get_value($array, 'key,key_2,key_3' ));
```

https://3v4l.org/mnvOs

You can use the input string you have with a str_replace.
But I don't understand the logic in it. They are all keys, but only the second and third have `[]` around them.

See here for str_replace example: https://3v4l.org/BObTk

Comment: Great, the str_replace example is working exactly the way I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass the argument to the function as mentioned in your code. If you want to print all the values or print a value of a specific key, you'll have to pass the key to the function as a string.

Consider the example below:

```
function get_value( $key = null ) {
    $array = [
       'key' => [
          'key_2' => array(
             'key_3' => 'Value 3'
          )
       ],
    ];

    $keys = explode('|', $key);
    $result = '';
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (empty($result)) {
            $result = $array[$key];       
        } else {
            $result = $result[$key];     
        }
    }

    echo $result;
}
```

Now if you pass get_value('key|key_2|key_3'), this will work.

Also the scope in php is not as same as in javascript. you cannot access the outside function variables inside a function. Refer this article for more info on scopes [Variable Scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the array is 5 levels deep?

Comment: This is not the way I explained in the question.

Comment: Ok. you've edited the question. I missed that as I was focussed on the answer. Let me edit it.